# Extract id out of a div when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've checked around in the forum and thought that I had it figured out:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    months = ['January','Februari','Mars','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
    days = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]

    for(i = 1; i <= 12; i++){
        $('.months').append('<div class="month" id='+i+'><p>'+months[i-1]+'</p></div>');
    }

    for(j = 1; j<=31; j++){
        $('.days').append('<div class="numberDays"><p>'+j+'</p></div>');
    }

    $('.months').click(function(){
        var id = this.id;
        alert(id);
        //$().css({'background':'red'});
    });
});
```

The plan was basically to get the `id` of the clicked div (using class `months`) and change its background to red without changing the other div's background color. But `this.id` returns nothing, nada, it's completely blank.

I also used:

```
$('.months').clicked(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr(id);
   alert(id);
});
```

But `id` ended up being undefined.

Comment: You need to bind to the child `div`, `.months` is the parent.

Comment: Noticed it! wow I feel really stupid. maybe I should remove the post?

Answer (score 0):

[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) inserts content *within* the div specified. In other words, you are binding the click event to the parent `.months`, you need to bind it to the children:

DEMO: https://jsbin.com/kebisusufi/edit?html,js,output

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var months = ['January','Februari','Mars','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
  var days = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];

  for(i = 1; i <= 12; i++){
    $('.months').append('<div class="month" id='+i+'><p>'+months[i-1]+'</p></div>');
  }
  for(j = 1; j<=31; j++){
    $('.days').append('<div class="numberDays"><p>'+j+'</p></div>');
  }

  // you can also use $('.month') or any other selector
  $('.months div').click(function(){ 
    var id = this.id;
    alert(id);
    //$().css({'background':'red'});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.months')
```

is the parent div for the other month div. You just selected the parent. It should be

```
$('.month').click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr(id);
  alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need id here to apply css, you can simply use:

```js
$(function() {

  var months = ['January', 'Februari', 'Mars', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

  for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    $('.months').append('<div class="month" id=' + i + '><p>' + months[i - 1] + '</p></div>');
  }

  $('.months').on('click', 'div', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.months').find('div').css({
      'background': 'inherit'
    }); //clear previous selection
    $(this).css({
      'background': 'red'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="months"></div>
```

Since there is nothing dynamic about css, you can go for `$.addClass()` and `$.removeClass()`:

```js
$(function() {

  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

  $.each(months, function(_, txt) {
    $('.months').append('<div class="month">' + txt + '</div>');
  });

  $('.months').on('click', 'div', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.months').find('div').removeClass('mark'); //clear previous selection
    $(this).addClass('mark');
  });
});
```

```css
.month {
  padding: 3px 4px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mark {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="months"></div>
```

Still if you looking to get the id:

```js
$(function() {

  var months = ['January', 'Februari', 'Mars', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

  for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    $('.months').append('<div class="month" id=' + i + '><p>' + months[i - 1] + '</p></div>');
  }

  $('.months').on('click', 'div', function(e) {
    alert(this.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="months"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
   <script>

$( document ).ready(function() {

months = ['January','Februari','Mars','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
days = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]

for(i = 1; i <= 12; i++){
    $('.months').append('<div class="month" id='+i+'><p>'+months[i-1]+'</p></div>');
}
for(j = 1; j<=31; j++){
    $('.days').append('<div class="numberDays"><p>'+j+'</p></div>');
}
$('.month').click(function(){
    var id = this.id;
    alert(id);
    //$().css({'background':'red'});
});
});
</script>
```

The problem is the months is related to the div rather than the individual months whose class is "month". This should work as expected.